# chrome extension message passing between extension-inner page and background script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I use a extension inner page(chrome-extension://) to request permission, and send result to background.

in extension inner page:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    chrome.permissions.request({
        permissions: permissions,
        origins: origin
    }, function(granted) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({route: '/permissionRequest', data: {command: 'Response', result: granted}}, function(){});
    });
}, false);
```

It looks well.But when I click the button, it open a new tab, url like chrome-extension://.../authorizehtml?undefined. The message send.

I don't know why it open a new tab like that.

And the, I found, if I change the key name 'data' to other name, it never open new tab.The official document don't talk about it.

I hava no idea about it.

Comment: What element is `btn` in this context?

Comment: Yes, btn in the inner page.

Comment: a button let user to click,and trigger permission request

Comment: But _what_ is it? `<button>`? `<a>`?

Comment: neither <button> or <a> work well.